# Search two keyword in full-text field

Tags: sphinx

I need to search two keyword (between)

Eg 1: I am going to buy **Mac Air** and **Mac Mini** for my brother. Here i need to get all data with has the keyword **Mac Air** and **Mac Mini**.

Eg 2: I will buy a car cost between **$5000** to **$10000** . Here i want to search for between.

Eg 3.1: I have some second hand goods ( x, y, z ) x cost **$300** y cost **$560** z cost **$50**.If any one need to buy this, Please contact 1800345123123.

Eg 3.2: I have some second hand goods ( a, b, c ) a cost **$1300** b cost **$660*** c cost **$50**.If any one need to buy this, Please contact 1800345123123.

In this example i need to find the minimum and max range, Say i need to find from **$100** to **$600**. i should get  Eg 3.1 but not  Eg 3.2.

How can i do all this in Sphinx ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide filter for each search like search between range for car cost, simple search for Mac Air and Mac mini, separate filter for second hand goods.This can not be accomplished in single search query.

For **price range**, you can use following

```
$cl->SetFilterRange ( $attribute, $min, $max, $exclude=false )
```

For **Mac Air** and **Mac mini**:

```
$cl->SetMatchMode ( SPH_MATCH_ANY );
```

When visitor will enter Mac he will get all results

For other two examples, need more details on database schema.

Comment: The data is already indexed for full-text field (summary). This filed will have  1000's of data like eg3.1 and 3.2. our goal is to fine the the data which mach the range from some $ to some $.

Comment: In this case SetFilterRange will perfectly.

Comment: I will implement and will be back :) Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: SetFilterRange takes int value and create query like ```SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE MATCH('@name("^Abhilash$")') AND summary BETWEEN 100 AND 600  ORDER BY date_ts DESC LIMIT 0,100``` This is not giving any result . I think it not working with SetFilterRange. we have to find some other way ....

Comment: summary has the text "I have some second hand goods ( x, y, z ) x cost $300 y cost $560 z cost $50.If any one need to buy this, Please contact 1800345123123."

Comment: Is Summary one of the indexed field? I need some more information about schema.

Comment: This is a single table 'Item' all the fields are indexed.

Comment: sql_field_string=summary , sql_field_string=name .